# "Undefined variable: post" when attempting to use @foreach in a blade template on a fresh install of Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

As the title says, when I try to use `@foreach($posts as $post)`, I get an error that `$post` is undefined.

I'm guessing I've probably made some simple mistake or something like that, but I haven't been able to figure out what the problem is, so I'm asking here.

It's a pretty fresh install of Laravel 5.7.

My `web.php` looks like this.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $posts = App\Post::all();
    return view('landing', compact('posts'));
});
```

I've got a `landing.blade.php` file in `resources/views` which includes a partial using `@include('partials.posts')`. In `resources/views/partials/` there's a `posts.blade.php` which has this.

```
$foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
$endforeach
```

And when I navigate to `/` in my browser, I get a `Undefined variable: post` error where it highlights `<?php echo e($post->title); ?>`, which correlates to `{{ $post->title }}`.

If I put `<?php dd($posts) ?>` before the `@foreach`, then it returns a collection with an array of my dummy posts, so it does seem like my posts are being passed to the view.

[image: The results of dd($posts)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@foreach & @endforeach` instead of `$foreach & $endforeach`.
Hence use `@` instead of `$`.

Comment: Wow, that was a stupid mistake on my part. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of what you have given for loop

`@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
@endforeach`